# SQL Server Select CASE WHEN inside where condition

Tags: sql-server-2012

My code is like this

```
SELECT A, B, C 
FROM tb_1 
WHERE C = (SELECT CASE WHEN (B > C) THEN C ELSE NULL END FROM tb_2)
```

I want to select row from `tb_1` with specified condition. When result of subquery is value of column C, it works well. But when the result is NULL, it cannot select the data. Because SQL Server cannot execute something like this

```
SELECT A, B, C 
FROM tb_1 
WHERE C = NULL
```

but, it should be like this

```
SELECT A, B, C 
FROM tb_1 
WHERE C IS NULL
```

Can anybody help me? I still want to insert subquery (select case when) to that condition

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table `tb_2` design is not clear from your question. Assuming the `tb_2` structure be same as `tb_1`, I think the following would work, but it all depends on your data (especially values in the column `C`). For example, if the values saved in `C` never be -9999, then you could use `ISNULL` in the `WHERE` clause as below. However, I would recommend to avoid subqueries where possible.

```
WHERE ISNULL(C, -9999) IN (SELECT CASE WHEN (B > C) THEN ISNULL(C, -9999) ELSE -9999 END FROM @t2)
```

Illustration:

```
GO
DECLARE @T1 TABLE (A INT, B INT, C INT)
INSERT INTO @T1 (A, B)VALUES (10, 20),(1, 2)

DECLARE @T2 TABLE (A INT, B INT, C INT)
INSERT INTO @T2 (A, B)VALUES (10, 20),(1, 2)

SELECT A, B, C 
FROM @t1 
WHERE ISNULL(C, -9999) IN (SELECT CASE WHEN (A > B) THEN ISNULL(C, -9999) ELSE -9999 END FROM @t2)
```